# SQL Query to find the activity time of each user

Tags: sql, sqlite, gaps-and-islands

How can we use this data to calculate the activity of each user in each period?

```
user_id       date            status 
 101        2018-01-1          1 
 101        2018-01-2          0 
 101        2018-01-3          1   
 101        2018-01-4          1 
 101        2018-01-5          1
```

Output:

```
 user_id  start_date     end_date  status  length 
   101    2018-01-1    2018-01-1    1      1
   101    2018-01-2    2018-01-2    0      1
   101    2018-01-3    2018-01-5    1      3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can group them together using by subtracting a sequence:

```
select user_id, status, min(date), max(date),
       julianday(max(date)) - julianday(min(date)) as length
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, status order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by user_id, status, date(date, '-' || seqnum || ' day')
order by user_id, length;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fc548cf3f13ba55de8c17c3775b80c58) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you so much
but how can I add status between max(date) and length
and 
rename min(date) to start_date??

Comment: @alirezana . . . Oops.  I put the status in the `group  by`, but not the `select`.  Fixed.